# The file '/test.aspx' does not exist. CheckVirtualFileExists exception

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

When hosting a website in an Azure web app, I get the this error when trying to access a non existing **aspx** file.

I'm expecting to get a 404 response, but instead I get a 500 exception.

I request an other file type I get the expected 404 response.

When I run the same site on an IIS I get the expected 404 for the aspx file

**Failed Request Trace**: [Link to Failed Request Trace](https://verticacloud-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ros_vertica_dk/EdBPmxzsm8NHu8Of12CrFiQBSuGziA2xeNa8KA-zcPrV_g?e=msd40c)

**Stacktrace**

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The file '/test.aspx' does not exist. at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp
 at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute(
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0(
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm expecting to get a 404 response, but instead I get a 500 exception.

The ASP.NET pipeline tries to find the handler for the request that ends with `/test.aspx`, which is actually the page itself, unless you've routed the request to some other URL.

If it can't find this handler, you get the error. **It's not a 404 because the request didn't even get handled.** So the actual status code returned is 500.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How come I get a 404 for "test.asp" or "test.zxy"?

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items).